# Error : requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when I try py to exe

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I wanted to make an application that shows the price of bitcoin on the screen, but when I turn it to exe, I get the error I mentioned above, and I'd appreciate it if you'd help me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitcoin.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "bitexen_client\api.py", line 214, in get_order_book
  File "bitexen_client\api.py", line 104, in _query_public
  File "bitexen_client\api.py", line 77, in _query
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 501, in get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[10868] Failed to execute script bitcoin
```

I looked elsewhere for a solution to this problem, but it was too complicated or the problem wasn't solved.

Note: I'm so new to python please simply explain

```
import os
import requests
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from bitexen_client import API

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

api = API(uri = 'https://bitexen.com/')

def refresh():

    btctry.set(api.get_order_book('BTCTRY')['ticker']['last_price'])
    label_value_btctry.config(text = btctry.get())
    label_value_btctry.after(5000, refresh)

def refresh2():
    btcusdt.set(api.get_order_book('BTCUSDT')['ticker']['last_price'])
    label_value_btcusdt.config(text = "  " + btcusdt.get())
    label_value_btcusdt.after(6000, refresh2)

btctry = StringVar()
btctry.set(api.get_order_book('BTCTRY')['ticker']['last_price'])

btcusdt = StringVar()
btcusdt.set(api.get_order_book('BTCUSDT')['ticker']['last_price'])

label_btctry = Label(root, text = 'BTC / TRY: ', font = (10))
label_btctry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)

label_value_btctry = Label(root, text = btctry.get(), font = (10))
label_value_btctry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 10)

label_btcusdt = Label(root, text = 'BTC / USDT: ', font = (10))
label_btcusdt.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)

label_value_btcusdt = Label(root, text = "  " + btcusdt.get(), font = (10))
label_value_btcusdt.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 10)

label_value_btctry.after(5000, refresh)
label_value_btcusdt.after(6000, refresh2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code. I converted it using py2exe and had no problems running it. It's possible the failure is to do with your dependencies not being up-to-date or your network configuration.

Comment: thank you for answer i should try using py2exe